# Consuming AMLS models deployed on edge device (RHEL VM) using azure iot edge

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy a model created and trained on azure machine learning service on edge VMs (Redhat Enterprise) uing iot-edge.
I am following this documentation which has most of the steps https://github.com/Azure/ai-toolkit-iot-edge/blob/master/IoT%20Edge%20anomaly%20detection%20tutorial/00-anomaly-detection-tutorial.ipynb

But it doesnt mentions how we can consume the model when deployed on edge devices (RHEL VM in this POC).
Do we have any sample code snippet for this, similar to what we have for ACI

Answer (score 0):

Support for deploying to the edge is in preview. Please follow the document to [Deploy Azure Machine Learning as an IoT Edge module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where#iotedge).

Please follow the below document to Consume the deployed model.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/running-cognitive-services-on-iot-edge/